# Is firebase right for my Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, android-syncadapter

I have an Android app that currently uses [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to retrieve/add/update and delete data from a cloud backend. I have implemented [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) pattern within my app. In the back-end, data is stores in relational DB tables and a servlet spits out JSON structure. I am considering to use [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com). I understand that firebase does not use relational tables and data is stored in JSON tree like structure.

1. Does Firebase make Retrofit networking library irrelevant?
2. Writing SyncAdapter requires lot of boilerplate code (in addition to XML, you need a Content Provider, Account, bind Service etc.). But, Firebase uses callbacks and your app is notified when data on the server automatically changes. Is Firebase a better choice than SyncAdapter?

Comment: Were you able to weight the pros and cons of the different approaches. Would like to know your discoveries